# Why React `renderToString` method doesn’t use clusters?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, performance, cluster-computing

#### Why this question?

I’m learning things about js performances and web rendering. [This post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web) was very useful.

If you follow some links you will land [here](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/operationalizing-node-js-for-server-side-rendering-c5ba718acfc9) and read this:

> User code in Node.js runs in a single thread, so for compute operations (as opposed to I/O), you can execute them concurrently, but not in parallel.

So I’ve read things about concurrency and parallelism in nodeJS. What I’ve learned is that nodeJS is:

- Parallel for I/O bound tasks since it’s handled by `libuv`
- Concurrent for CPU bound tasks

This explains why `renderToString` is a slow operation since it is CPU bound. But it seems that there is a way to enable parallelism of CPU bound tasks in nodejs: [clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).

#### The question

This is why I’m here. Do you know why `renderToString` isn’t clustered (don’t know if this is valid English)?

- Maybe it’s too complicated?
- Maybe it just can’t be done in parallel?
- Maybe it doesn't improve performances for some reason?

I would like to understand why. Because after those readings, I tend to think that nodeJS  is very performant when it comes to dealing with I/O, but it seems to also be performant for CPU bound tasks since you can create clusters. Nevertheless it doesn’t seems to be trivial and it’s a choice to consider in some specific cases.

So this leads us to one bonus question: what are the limitations/drawbacks of nodejs’s clusters ? (Excepting the fact that it seems to be complicated to setup and to maintain on large projects?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not make sense to place the abstraction at this level.

It is not hard to run a `renderToString()` as a cluster. For instance, you can easily use the [worker-farm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-farm) library.

The problem is this becomes hard to use in a beneficial way, because the "store" of data built for each incoming request must be in scope for the entire component tree that `renderToString()` works on.

Perhaps though with the experimental [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) node.js library, we might get some multi-threaded renderToString. But, the work on SSR (Server Side Rendering) of React is not nearly as active as the client.

Maybe with the work to allow React to suspend a tree its rendering, and start it up, we'll eventually have a thread that can continue rendering while primary thread acts on incoming request/action.

Comment: Just saw your answer, thanks, I understand it better right now :)